# After SplashScreen finish() app gets minimized

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I'm using finish() to end a thread in my SplashScreen activity and when I do the app gets minimized before going to Activity2. How can I end the SplashScreen activity and go to Activity2 without calling finish() so the app won't minimize?

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    /**
     * The thread to process splash screen events
     */
    private Thread mSplashThread;    

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Splash screen view
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        final SplashScreen sPlashScreen = this;   

        // The thread to wait for splash screen events
        mSplashThread =  new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                try {
                    synchronized(this){
                        // Wait given period of time or exit on touch
                        wait(5000);
                    }
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex){                    
                }

                finish();

                // Run next activity
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(sPlashScreen, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //stop();                    
            }
        };

        mSplashThread.start();        
    }

    /**
     * Processes splash screen touch events
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt)
    {
        if(evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            synchronized(mSplashThread){
                mSplashThread.notifyAll();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call finish after startActivity

```
    mSplashThread =  new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                synchronized(this){
                    // Wait given period of time or exit on touch
                    wait(5000);
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){                    
            }


            // Run next activity
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(sPlashScreen, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);



            //call finish after startActivity
            finish();
            //stop();                    
        }
    };

    mSplashThread.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

```
private class IntentLauncher extends Thread {
      @Override
      /**
       * Sleep for some time and than start new activity.
       */
      public void run() {
         try {
            // Sleeping
            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME*1000);
         } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
         }

         // Start main activity
         Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
         SplashActivity.this.startActivity(intent);


         SplashActivity.this.finish();
      }
    }
```